# Using Orfeo ToolBox in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, orfeo-toolbox

I want to use Orfeo ToolBox in Python. By using the OSGeo4W package, I installed an otb-python and otb-bin. After installing them, I tried the coding as below:

```
>>> from sys import argv
>>> import otbApplication

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import otbApplication
ImportError: No module named otbApplication
```

I wonder what I missed. My OS is the Windows 7 and Python version is 2.7.

Comment: what is the version of your otb?. AFAICT recent versions do not have osgeo4w packages.

Answer (score 1):

otb python packages are not installed in usual site-packages directory. they are in osgeo4w/lib/otb/python

so you must update PYTHONPATH to import python bindings